# Is it possible to make a particular column in a tablefield readonly?

Tags: entities

Since in my case I have three columns A, B and C. A and B holds a data and C stores the summation of those data. I wrote a custom javascript to do that and also tried to make column C readonly through javascript but the problem is while in a table rebuild the data in column C clears out but if I didn't apply readonly on column C then data remains. Any suggestions in this case will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you applying the readonly to the fields?

You need to use the FAPI '#attributes' property to set readonly like this:

```
'#attributes' => array(
    'readonly'=>'readonly',
);
```

You need to alter the form through hook_form_alter and addd the above property to the textfield you want readonly.

Comment: Actually I used:$form['field_project_resrc_budget_fund']['und']['0']['tablefield']['cell_1_3']['#disabled']=TRUE; inside my hook_form_alter to disable a particular cell of my tablefield and it makes the cell disable but the problem is whenever the table rebuild then it looses its value that is inside it.

Comment: I got you but instead please try this if this works:
$form['field_project_resrc_budget_fund']['und']['0']['tablefield']['cell_1_‌​3']['#attributes']['readonly']= 'readonly';

Comment: I tried that but it leads to me the blank white screen. It does not work.

Comment: well if its blank white screen its for sure a syntax error. Check for php syntax errors like missing semi-colons etc.

Comment: The way of declaring read only to the the form elements is not correct syntactically I tried the way that you mention and still no success.

Comment: Thanks @Neo it worked like charm. I spotted my error ! now it works.